# Drop down binding with enumeration type in knockout

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am not able to bind dropdown with enum value.In given code,I am getting all enumeration value as object in variable "mode" but its not getting bind in dropdown.
Here is my html code of dropdown.

```
<select data-bind="options:modes,value:Mode, 
                   optionsText:'Text',
                   optionsValue:'ID',
                   optionCaption:'Select Mode'"></select>
```

and the script is as follows:--

```
var NfsObject = {
    Name: '',
    Path: '',
    Extensions: '',
    Volume: '',           
    Mode: 0,
    ClientID: 0
}

function Nfs(data) {
    var mode = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.ToValues(typeof(NfsModeEnum)))');
    var self = this;
    this.modes = mode;
    this.clients = ko.observableArray([]);                       
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, NfsObject, self);
}
```

Comment: What have you in variable mode ? Is it well populated ? If not, check if @Html.Raw don't add double quotes and generated a valid JSON.

Comment: yes it is getting populated. as--mode-0-Object-Text:"Nfs", 1-Object-Text:"Ftp" 2-Object-Text:"Storage"

Comment: You haven't provided enough info to help you. I've tried to make [something of the code you've posted](http://jsfiddle.net/nkV2f/) but there's too much missing to get a repro.